# React Font Awsome import font variable names from JSON

Tags: json, reactjs, font-awesome-5

I have a JSON file that I import, part of it looks like this

```
"icons": [
  { "title": "Experience", "icon": "faGem" },
  { "title": "Courteous", "icon": "faThumbs" }
]
```

I loop over this in my code, the below code doesn't work because I need faGem as a variable, not "faGem" as a string

```
{icons.map((val, i) => (
  <li key={i} className={styles.icon}>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={val.icon} />
    <span className={styles.iconText}>{val.title}</span>
  </li>
))}
```

I tried eval and JSON.parse as well to convert the string, no luck

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Actually, you don't need to **faGem** as a variable. It can be a string as well. Please check https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react

Comment: nar, I tried that yesterday and again today, nothing renders when I try  <FontAwesomeIcon icon="faGem" />

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an array as icon value:

```
"icons": [
  { "title": "Experience", "icon": ['fas', 'faGem'] },
  ...
]
```

and then:

```
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={val.icon} />
```

Here is the doc:
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react

Comment: I tried that, nothing renders, it still see's it as a string i suppose